# Please synonymize [lg-p500] and [lg-optimus-one]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

[lg-p500](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lg-p500) and [lg-optimus-one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lg-optimus-one) would appear to be the same device. Please synonymize. (I suggest [lg-optimus-one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lg-optimus-one) should be the master.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done. Thanks for catching that.